# If a variable is a pointer to a structure, then which operator is used to access data members of the structure through the pointer variable?

Tags: c, api, pointers, data-structures

If a variable is a pointer to a structure in c, then which operator is used to access data members of the structure through the pointer variable?

Comment: In the general case you don't need to use pointers in C#. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just realised that your question is tagged C and C#. Please clarify which language you're question is about.

Comment: What do your textbook and lecture notes say?

Answer (score 0):

Use the arrow `->` operator.

Example:
`structPointer->member`

Here's a more in-depth explaination: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access